# How to run a bash function inside python subprocess?

Tags: python, bash

I am trying to integrate my bash script with the python wrapper, but here I am having an issue. I am not able to call a function from my bash script after sourcing in the python subprocess. It is not working. Is there any way around?

For example:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call(['/bin/bash', '-c' ,'source validation_utils.sh;','press_any_key_to_continue'])
```

Comment: You might want to try `'source validation_utils.sh; press_any_key_to_continue'` as the third and final argument, as the `-c` flag should be one continuous argument for the two statements you need to execute via `bash`.

Comment: @metatoaster Yes you are right!! Thanks